# New to Javascript, style is not affecting anything

Tags: javascript, tags, styles

> It's for this website lbitaliantours.com, I just don't undertstand why
>   it is not working.

```
 <script>
        var width = window.innerWidth
        console.log(width);
        function myFunction() {if (width < 900) {
        var buffalo = document.getElementById("featured");
        buffalo.style.font = "65px";
        }
        }
        myFunction();
        console.log(buffalo);

    </script>
```

Comment: Really I just need a basic script to resize elements when the window size changes. I'm just testing it with the font for that particular id, but really just need the menu to stop from stacking. If you go to the website lbitaliantours.com you will see what I mean. So what I decided to do is resize the font which seems to work but I need this javascript to work and it's not :(

Comment: Use CSS media queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

use fontSize, instead of font

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
            console.log(width);
            function myFunction() {
                if (width < 9000) {
                    var buffalo = document.getElementById("featured");
                    buffalo.style.fontSize = "65px";
                }
            }
            myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to use CSS media queries. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/howudi/edit?html,output) an example. As you resize the browser, once it goes below 500px, you will see that the text changes it font size.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the property you are referring requires more parameters. If you are setting property font, this should be done like this . . . `element.style.font = '65px arial, sans-serif` if you only want to change the size you have to specify that `element.style.fontSize = '65px'`